# How to add constrain to One2many field in Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

If have two entities "payment" and "bill". With each payment the user must be able to pay one or more "biils" That is done by adding a One2Many field (of type bill) in the payment model. How can I add a constrain to ensure that a payment should have at least one bill ? (ensure that the One2Many list is not empty). I have tried this code but it is not working cause the user can create one payment without having to add "bill" to the One2Many Bills attibute.

```
class PaymentCenter(models.Model):
    _name = 'center.payment'
    _description = 'Payment'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'mail.activity.mixin']

    bill_ids = fields.One2many('center.bill',
                                    "payment_id",
                                    string=" Bills", required=True)

    @api.constrains('bill_ids')
    def _constrains_bill_ids(self):
        if not self.bill_ids or len(self.bill_ids)==0:
            raise ValidationError("You must add at least one bill to the payment")

class BillCenter(models.Model):
    _name = 'center.bill'
    _inherits = {'ir.attachment': 'attachment_id'}

    payment_id = fields.Many2one('center.payment', string="Payment")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@constrains` will be triggered only if the declared fields in the
decorated method are included in the `create` or `write` call.
It implies that fields not present in a view will not trigger a call
during record creation.
A override of `create` is necessary to make
sure a constraint will always be triggered (e.g. to test the absence of
value).

Try to override `create` method and check if `bill_ids` is present:

```
@api.model
def create(self, values):
    if 'bill_ids' not in values:
        values['bill_ids'] = False
    return super(PaymentCenter, self).create(values)
```

When You add the code above the constrains should work and If you try to delete bills and save It raises a validation error (it is because of `bill_ids` is present in `values` argument of write method. *Example of one bill deleted `{'bill_ids': [[2, id, False]]}`*).

*You can also raise the error in the create method*.

You can let users create payments without filling `bill_ids` and raise a user error when they try to validate a payment without a bill.

```
def validate_payment(self):
    for payment in self:
        if not payment.bill_ids:
            raise UserError(_("You must add at least one bill to the payment."))
```

Comment: Thank you once again. I am new with odoo and glad to find help

Comment: Is there any place where I can documentation about the internal funtioning of Odoo?, something like " @constrains will be triggered only if the declared fields in the decorated method are included in the create or write call. "

Comment: Yes of course, `constrains` can be found at [ORM](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html). Check the [developer documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/index.html) and you can start with [Building a Module](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/howtos/backend.html). You can also check the [api source code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/api.py#L123)

Answer (score 0):

Use validator function..

```
from django.db import models  
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError 

# validator function 
def validate_bill_ids(value): 
    if not value: 
        raise ValidationError("Bills id required") 


class YourModel(models.Model): 
    bill_ids = fields.One2many('center.bill',
                                    "payment_id",
                                    string=" Bills", required=True,
                        validators =[validate_bill_ids] 
                        )
```